How to show comments in Word listed on the right side instead of as balloons?
I would like to show the comments in Word in the style that is shown below.

However in my word they always display like this (as 'balloons')

That is, they display as balloons only and the comment appears when I click on the balloon. I want to display them as above, i.e. in a list underneath each other. I cannot figure out how to switch between the one and the other display style.
EDIT:
@Reddy Lutonadio suggested to enable modern comments, but this option is not available. See screenshot below. I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019.



Go to File -> Options -> General. Under User Interface options, select Enable modern comments. Press OK.
Restart Word.



Thanks but this option is not available in my word, see screenshot in Edit above.

This should work -- "Show Only Comments and Formatting in Balloons":


No it doesn't. However, 'show revisions in Balloons' worked

Strange. In another document your suggested solution works. I do not understand this.
